# Font changed in togglebutton IsChecked property wpf

Tags: wpf, fonts, togglebutton

I've a toggle button :

```
                    <Label x:Name="Text" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF1B6625" Margin="30,0,0,0" 
                                         FontSize="15" Background="#0016792C" Content="pause"
                                         FontFamily="/UIapp;component/Resources/Fonts/#Arial" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>



                    <Image x:Name="Icon" 
                           Width="14" Height="14" 
                           Margin="10,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Source="{DynamicResource PlayIcon}">
                    </Image>
```

and in ControlTemplate.Triggers i have :

```
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource PauseIcon}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Content" Value="play"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Margin" Value="25,0,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>                        
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

but from some reason, when i click on the button, i get a different font than it was before the click.

any idea for the reason ?

thanks

Comment: I'm confused... I don't see a button or a checkbox in the code you included.  Can you include more of your xaml?

Comment: as far as the code above is concerned, there is no reason for this change of font. So the issue probably lies somewhere else (like in an other style somewhere in your app's resources for instance). You need to explain a bit more and provide your whole xaml template code at least

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand the relation between Label and toggle button.
For font change, try using [Snoop tool](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

This may help you in understanding the cause of font change.